# Using an expression as an input to a function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I wanted to create a redundant function that joins 2 dataframes:

```
def foo(df1, df2, how = None, on = None):
   df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = how, on = on)
   return df
```

**how** is a string argument so thats not a problem. However, the **on** argument would be an expression... lets say:

```
df1.id == df2.id

join_df = foo(df1, df2, how='left', on=df1.id == df2.id) #this would fail
```

How could you input this as an argument to the function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do it as it is in SQL. Try this:

```
def foo(df1, df2, how = None, right_on=None, left_on=None):
   df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = how, right_on=right_on, left_on=left_on)
   return df
```

the right_on gets the column name from df1, and the left_on gets it from df2.

```
join_df = foo(df1, df2, how='left', right_on='id', left_on='id')
```